# apexcharts line break in label produces duplicate labels

Tags: apexcharts

I have implemented some charts with apexcharts. One of them has to long labels, even for rotating. Instead I want to do linebreaks. I have copied code from
https://apexcharts.com/docs/multiline-text-and-line-breaks-in-axes-labels/

but even this is giving this result:

[image]

My code is:

```
   var options = {
        series:[ {name: '11', data: [554,182,211,130,190,6,28,0,0,0]}, {name: '10', data: [268,268,168,145,124,62,17,21,0,0]},{name: '9', data: [287,321,164,112,22,47,20,27,0,0]},{name: '8', data: [302,363,161,169,31,16,23,66,0,0]},{name: '7', data: [362,56,139,111,113,6,14,31,0,1]},{name: '6', data: [365,367,182,76,29,0,19,47,0,0]}, {name: '5', data: [335,455,235,100,116,8,15,21,0,0]},{name: '4', data: [288,414,171,5,146,12,28,46,0,0]},{name: '3', data: [305,352,257,72,43,113,20,0,7,0]},{name: '2', data: [272,109,181,46,295,106,32,0,15,50]},{name: '1', data: [342,181,189,64,357,19,26,0,84,23]},{name: '0', data: [321,217,151,65,216,12,19,0,100,9]} ],
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            height: 400,
            width: 800
        },
   xaxis: {
            categories: [    ['Apples', 'sdf'],
                'Strawberries',
                'Pineapples',
                ['Sugar', 'Baby', 'Watermelon'],
                ['Prickly', 'Pear'],
                'Pears',
                ['Quararibea', 'cordata'],
                'Pomegranates',
                'Tangerines',
                'sasfdsf'
            ],
    };
```

Does anyone see what I have done wrong?
Thanks
Max

Comment: I did replicate the behavior from your image in the first attempt I made, but now I can't anymore, it works as advertised https://jsfiddle.net/pv79bt3f/ Do you see any difference?

Comment: I found the problem, the downloaded apexcharts.min.js obciously differs from the one online. Thanks for the jsfiddle!